# Having trouble understanding the predictions array in classification model evaluation

Tags: deep-learning, bert-language-model, text-classification

I'm working on a sarcasm detector with the BERT model (binary classification). Currently, I'm having trouble with the model evaluation as I don't really understand the predictions array. The model should output 1 for sarcastic and 0 for not, but the predictions don't output that. Please let me know if more code is needed. Thank you!

model:

```
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification, AdamW, BertConfig

# Load BertForSequenceClassification, the pretrained BERT model with a single 
# linear classification layer on top. 
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "bert-base-uncased", # Use the 12-layer BERT model, with an uncased vocab.
    num_labels = 2, # The number of output labels--2 for binary classification.
                    # You can increase this for multi-class tasks.   
    output_attentions = False, # Whether the model returns attentions weights.
    output_hidden_states = False, # Whether the model returns all hidden-states.
    attention_probs_dropout_prob=0.25,
    hidden_dropout_prob=0.25
)

# Tell pytorch to run this model on the GPU.
model.cuda()
```

evaluation:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd

print('Predicting labels for {:,} test sentences...'.format(len(eval_input_ids)))

# Put model in evaluation mode
model.eval()

predictions , true_labels = [], []


# iterate over test data
for batch in eval_dataloader:
  batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
  
  # Unpack the inputs from our dataloader
  b_input_ids, b_input_mask, b_labels = batch
  
  # Telling the model not to compute or store gradients, saving memory and 
  # speeding up prediction
  with torch.no_grad():
      # Forward pass, calculate logit predictions.
      result = model(b_input_ids, 
                     token_type_ids=None, 
                     attention_mask=b_input_mask,
                     return_dict=True)

  logits = result.logits

  # Move logits and labels to CPU
  logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
  label_ids = b_labels.to('cpu').numpy()
  
  # Store predictions and true labels
  predictions.append(logits)
  true_labels.append(label_ids)

true_labels[1]
predictions[1]
```

output:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
   0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]) <-- true_labels[1]
array([[ 2.9316974 , -2.855342  ],
   [ 3.4540875 , -3.3177233 ],
   [ 2.7424026 , -2.6472614 ],
   [-3.4326897 ,  3.330751  ],
   [ 3.7238903 , -3.7757814 ],
   [-3.208891  ,  3.175109  ],
   [ 3.0500402 , -2.8103237 ],
   [ 3.8333693 , -3.9073608 ],
   [-3.2779126 ,  3.231213  ],
   [ 1.484127  , -1.2610332 ],
   [ 3.686339  , -3.7582958 ],
   [-2.1883147 ,  2.205132  ],
   [-3.274582  ,  3.2254982 ],
   [-1.606854  ,  1.6213335 ],
   [ 3.7080388 , -3.6854186 ],
   [-2.351147  ,  2.365543  ],
   [-3.7317555 ,  3.4833894 ],
   [ 3.2413306 , -3.2116275 ],
   [ 3.7413723 , -3.7767386 ],
   [-3.6293464 ,  3.4446163 ],
   [ 3.7779078 , -3.9025154 ],
   [-3.5576923 ,  3.403335  ],
   [ 3.6226897 , -3.6370063 ],
   [-3.7081888 ,  3.4720154 ],
   [ 1.1533121 , -0.8105195 ],
   [ 1.0573612 , -0.69238156],
   [ 3.4189024 , -3.4764926 ],
   [-0.13847755,  0.450572  ],
   [ 3.7248163 , -3.7781181 ],
   [-3.2015219 ,  3.1719215 ],
   [-2.1409311 ,  2.1202204 ],
   [-3.470693  ,  3.358798  ]], dtype=float32) <-- predictions[1]
```

Comment: Did you try changing the num_labels to 1?

Comment: These values are logits, do you know what those are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two values because you have two classes (0=no, 1=yes). These values are logits, which when fed into a softmax function gives the probability of each class. If you want to know whether the sample is classified as sarcasm or not, just take the class with the highest logit:

```
predictions = a.max(1)[1]
print(predictions)
```